# Deploying J2EE Web Application on Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I had been working on amazon web services from couple of days and it is giving me a hard time. All the want it to deploy my `J2ee` web application on Amazon web Services. I had used the following approach:

1) In had installed the AWS toolkit on eclipse.
2) I had deployed the sample web application of the amazon web services but it is without database. It's a static web page.

But i want to deploy my `j2ee` web application on `aws` with `apache` `tomcat 7` as server and mysql database server.  Can any one explain me how to deploy the j2ee web app on the aws? I would be highly thankful to you.

Comment: Start an aws ec2 instance and install apache tomcat and mysql in it

Comment: I had already started ec2 instance ...

Comment: Hi sailesh.. i had a running amazon ec2 linux instances running .. i had connected to the remote linux machine using putty but i cant proceed further...  i also tried using elastic beanstalk but that too didnt worked

Comment: Tell me what exactly you see on the command screen

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/elasticbeanstalk/what-is) 
If you use tomcat with your Java EE application, it become easier because it already  have some templates for that. [Creating and Deploying Elastic Beanstalk Applications in Java Using AWS Toolkit for Eclipse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html)

As for mysql, AWS also has the RDS which can do it perfectly. Just modify your database.config in your Java EE application according to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.rds.html).

Hope it will help.